# Configuration file in Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Can you please tell me how does the configuration file work in Azure functions? Visual Studio creates a `local.settings.json` file when creating an Azure function project but I guess that's local and cannot be deployed on Azure. Should I create an `App.config` file and probably use CloudConfigurationManager to access the setting variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, when developing locally, the configuration values are read from `local.settings.json`.

However, when your function is running in Azure, the configuration values are read from [App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings).

So simply add an app setting and you can access it the same way you would access it if the function was running locally.

Comment: This post will give you a little more depth into what local.settings.json is all about.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360238/using-configurationbuilder-in-functionsstartup/64901557#64901557