# How to use async methods to create Cosmos Client in DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to use Cosmos DB in my ASP.net 5 WebAPI project. To create the client I want to use Dependency injection to inject it to my Service. To do so I created this statement in my `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

```
services.AddSingleton(async s => {
    var dbConfig = Configuration.GetSection("Database");
    var conn = dbConfig["ConnectionString"];
    var dbName = dbConfig["DbName"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(conn))
    {
       throw new ConfigurationErrorsException();
    }
    var client = new CosmosClient(conn);
    await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(dbName);
    return client;
});
```

But in this case I get an error in my service when I try to inject it via:

```
public ProductService(ILogger<ProductService> logger, CosmosClient client)
{
    this._client = client;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

Because my arrow function returns `Task<CosmosClient>` instead of `CosmosClient`. But how can I change that therefore Database-creation methos is async and I have to use await?!

THanks

Comment: I've tackled this in my own code by using a factory pattern where the create method is async, and then going via the factory from request code to get a client. The factory is non-async so resolves from DI, and then requests that need the client can asynchronously create a client and use it.

Comment: Since the client is being registered as a singleton, I would suggest moving the asynchronous operation into a hosted service to be executed on startup

Comment: Another option would be to create an asynchronous event handler to create the database. Have a look at an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59474646/5233410

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's Dependency Injection does not support `async`.

I recommend having a separate "schema deployer" project that is run as part of your deployment (or locally to create databases on the emulator). Then you can remove the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync` call and inject `CosmosClient`.

If you must use `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync` from within your application (and not during deployment), then you will need to [inject an asynchronous factory](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html):

```
public sealed class CosmosClientFactory
{
  private readonly Lazy<Task<CosmosClient>> _lazy;

  public CosmosClientFactory(Configuration configuration)
  {
    _lazy = new(async () =>
    {
      var dbConfig = configuration.GetSection("Database");
      var conn = dbConfig["ConnectionString"];
      var dbName = dbConfig["DbName"];
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(conn))
      {
       throw new ConfigurationErrorsException();
      }
      var client = new CosmosClient(conn);
      await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(dbName);
      return client;
    });
  }

  public Task<CosmosClient> CreateAsync() => _lazy.Value;
}
```

Usage:

```
private readonly CosmosClientFactory _clientFactory;
public ProductService(ILogger<ProductService> logger, CosmosClientFactory clientFactory)
{
  _clientFactory = clientFactory;
  _logger = logger;
}
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
  var client = await _clientFactory.CreateAsync();
  await client.DoSomethingAsync();
}
```