# Access IConfiguration in other classes of FunctionsStartup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions

How I access IConfiguration object in classes of Azure Functions project. I am new to this type of code, but I need to access IConfiguration in some of the class files defined in the project.

Ex: in the TestService, also in SampleService which is not listed Startup.cs

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
   var config = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
   builder.Services.AddTransient<ITestService, TestService>();
}
```

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474070/how-to-inject-or-use-iconfiguration-in-azure-function-v3-with-dependency-injecti

Comment: @SunnyDark Thanks for quick response. Let me check the link.

Comment: @DeepDave-MT not yet Dave. If you know something please post here. It will help me as well as others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou [SunnyDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2560673/sunnydark). Posting your suggestion as an answer so that it will be helpful for other community members who face similar kind of issues.

`IConfiguration` is added to the service collection by default as part of the start up, Below is the example for `IConfiguration`

```cs
public static class BootstrapCosmosDbClient {

    private static event EventHandler initializeDatabase = delegate { };

    public static IServiceCollection AddCosmosDbService(this IServiceCollection services) {

        Func<IServiceProvider, ICosmosDbService> factory = (sp) => {
            //resolve configuration
            IConfiguration configuration = sp.GetService<IConfiguration>();
            //and get the configured settings (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll)
            CosmosDbClientSettings cosmosDbClientSettings = configuration.Get<CosmosDbClientSettings>();
            string databaseName = cosmosDbClientSettings.CosmosDbDatabaseName;
            string containerName = cosmosDbClientSettings.CosmosDbCollectionName;
            string account = cosmosDbClientSettings.CosmosDbAccount;
            string key = cosmosDbClientSettings.CosmosDbKey;

            CosmosClientBuilder clientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(account, key);
            CosmosClient client = clientBuilder.WithConnectionModeDirect().Build();
            CosmosDbService cosmosDbService = new CosmosDbService(client, databaseName, containerName);

            //async event handler
            EventHandler handler = null;
            handler = async (sender, args) => {
                initializeDatabase -= handler; //unsubscribe
                DatabaseResponse database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
                await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName, "/id");
            };
            initializeDatabase += handler; //subscribe
            initializeDatabase(null, EventArgs.Empty); //raise the event to initialize db

            return cosmosDbService;
        };
        services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbService>(factory);
        return service;
    }
}
```

For Further information check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59474646/15969833) and [Web Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-dotnet-application#connect-to-cosmosdb).