# Environment variables are null when injecting IConfiguration into service collection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am trying to pass my local configurations within my azure functions into an iServiceCollection in another project with which this function has dependency.

I am working in .NET 6

Here is my function startup.cs based on the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474070/how-to-inject-or-use-iconfiguration-in-azure-function-v3-with-dependency-injecti)

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(DatabaseInit.Startup))]
namespace Edos.DatabaseInit;
public class Startup:FunctionsStartup
{


    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
       
        builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(configuration);
       
    }

}
```

And this is my local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "ServiceBusConnectionString": "myconnectionstring",
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

My function

```
public class CosmosInit
{
    private readonly IMessagingService _messagingService;


    public CosmosInit(IMessagingService messagingService)
    {
        _messagingService = messagingService;
        
    }
    [FunctionName("CosmosInit")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {

        await _messagingService.PushToTopic("demotopic", "message");

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

Here is the Above AddInfrastructure method in my dependency project of my Azure function

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    { 
        var serviceBusConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnectionString");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceBusConnectionString))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Please specify a valid ServiceBusConnectionString in the Azure Functions Settings or your local.settings.json file.");
        }

        //using AMQP as transport
        services.AddSingleton((s) => {
            return new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusConnectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions() { TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets });
        });
        services.AddScoped<IMessagingService, MessagingService>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

And this is where my method (Within the infrastructure project)

```
public class MessagingService: IMessagingService
{
    private readonly ServiceBusClient _serviceBusClient;

    public MessagingService(ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient)
    {
        _serviceBusClient = serviceBusClient;
    }
    // the sender used to publish messages to the topic
    
    public async Task<int> PushToTopic(string topic, string serviceMessage)
    {
        var sender = _serviceBusClient.CreateSender(topic);
        var message = new ServiceBusMessage(serviceMessage);
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
        return 1;

    }
}
```

But when executing there is no error. But within the infrastructure project Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnectionString") just shows as null. And I found no configurations its taking from the functions local.settings.json

Please suggest what I did wrong or how can I fix this.. please

Comment: If you send your configuration as parameter, why you try to read as Enviroment variable? Try using "configuration" inside your method AddInfrastructure and read it with "GetSection"

Comment: @Mate I tried this way in my infrastructure project  var serviceBusConnectionString = configuration.GetSection("ServiceBusConnectionString").Value; which is also null

Comment: please, do the same in Startup:FunctionsStartup , method Configure. To verify if  it's loading your  local.settings.json.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mate.. I just tried that and it returning null
var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
        var s = configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceBusConnectionString");
So is it because the way I am initializing the configuration?? So could you please suggest how can I pass the configuration into my infrastructure project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, try to find or add a code like

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

 Some class {

    ...
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: false)
        .Build();

        //just to verify
        var conn = builder.GetSection("ServiceBusConnectionString").Get<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(conn);
     ...
}
```

You could add it to your current method "Configure" , and keep the rest of your code as is.
Or verify if you have a previous point where the configuration is loaded.

**By default, configuration files such as appsettings.json are not automatically copied to the function app's output folder**. Update your .csproj file to match the following sample to ensure the files are copied.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

```
 Some class {

    ...
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: false)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables() //HERE!!

        //just to verify
        var conn = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnectionString");
        Console.WriteLine(conn);
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mate. I followed it and it simply does the job.. :) But one question, this will work fine for local.settings.json. But how come it work for taking values from Environment variables when deployed to azure??

Comment: Great! check the link and the update. You need to call " .AddEnvironmentVariables();"

Comment: Thats awesome.. Thats a lot man.. Btw I am wondering things getting complicated when new version comes which was easy in older versions of .net or I could be interpreting it wrong.. ;)

Comment: Embrace it. Change is the new normal.