# How to add custom configuration provider to azure functions

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-configuration

I implemented custom configuration provider and it works fine in a web app. But I also need to use it inside azure functions. And it seems like it's impossible at the moment. `IFunctionsHostBuilder` allows to get context which already have pre-built `IConfigurationRoot` instance. I cannot find a way to access to `IConfigurationBuilder` like in my web app. Has anyone managed to workaround it?

Comment: Check whether [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474070/how-to-inject-or-use-iconfiguration-in-azure-function-v3-with-dependency-injecti) helps you.

Comment: @RogersonNazário Thanks, one of the answers mentions `ConfigureAppConfiguration` which should resolve my issue, will try it shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to `Rogerson Nazário` for the comments.

> It can be done by using a custom configuration provider in Azure Functions.

By creating a class and making it to implement the `IConfigurationProvider` interface.
And the created class is responsible for retrieving configuration values from the custom source and adding them to the `IConfigurationBuilder`.

And also create a class that implements the `IConfigurationSource` interface. This class will be responsible for creating an instance of the custom configuration provider.

In Startup class, add custom configuration source to the `IConfigurationBuilder`. You can do this by calling the Add method on the `IConfigurationBuilder` and passing in an instance of your `IConfigurationSource` implementation.

```
public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigurationBuilder
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Add<MyCustomConfigurationSource>();
}
```

Use the IConfiguration instance in Azure Function.

You can do this by injecting an instance of IConfiguration into Azure Function using the FunctionName attribute.

```
public static class MyFunction
{
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Use configuration values here
    }
}
```

Using custom configuration providers to Azure Functions by overriding the ConfigureAppConfiguration method
in function app's StartUp class.

Thanks @ `Glenn Gailey` for the [functions-dotnet-dependency-injection code.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection.md)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace
{ public class Startup : FunctionsStartup { public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder) { FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext(); builder.ConfigurationBuilder .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false) .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, $"appsettings.{context.EnvironmentName}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false) .AddEnvironmentVariables(); }
}
}
```